# How to embed player into web page?

Tags: html, browser

I want to embed MPC player into web page, any samples?

MPC player I mean => http://sourceforge.net/projects/guliverkli/

Answer (score 1):

Here are some widgets..

http://www.ohloh.net/p/mpc-hc/widgets

Are these what you are looking for?

Try this code:

```
<OBJECT id="VIDEO" width="320" height="240" 
style="position:absolute; left:0;top:0;"
CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6"
type="application/x-oleobject">

<PARAM NAME="URL" VALUE="your file or url">
<PARAM NAME="SendPlayStateChangeEvents" VALUE="True">
<PARAM NAME="AutoStart" VALUE="True">
<PARAM name="uiMode" value="none">
<PARAM name="PlayCount" value="9999">
</OBJECT>
```

Comment: @CodeToGlory, I am confused. 1. there is a list, which one do you mean? 2. I did not see code which imports and invokes mpc player, but codes which calls javascript from other site like http://www.ohloh.net/. Could you explain what that javascript doing please? 3. I want to see a sample which pass a parameter (media file URL) to mpc player, but I did not see such a sample, appreciate if you could share/refer a simple sample like this?

Comment: Try this out:

<OBJECT id="VIDEO" width="320" height="240" 
 style="position:absolute; left:0;top:0;"
 CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6"
 type="application/x-oleobject">
 
 <PARAM NAME="URL" VALUE="your file or url">
 <PARAM NAME="SendPlayStateChangeEvents" VALUE="True">
 <PARAM NAME="AutoStart" VALUE="True">
 <PARAM name="uiMode" value="none">
 <PARAM name="PlayCount" value="9999"&gt

Comment: @CodeToGlory, I am confused. How do you know CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6 maps to MPC player?

Comment: @SrikarDoddi - This is a very old question, but still active topic today. Could you update your link. It isn't valid any more - 404.